# binary tree, represented by nested parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

I'm new to python, I'm building a tree, this is my code:

```
class BinaryTree():
    def __init__(self, dado, left = None, right = None):
        self.dado = dado
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

I want to make a function to represent the binary tree,
represented by nested parentheses. This function receives the root and shows, in one line, the structure of the elements.
For example, the tree:

[image]

is displayed as `(1 (2 () ()) (3 () (4 () ())))`.

In this tree, the root of the tree is represented by the outermost parentheses, followed by the parentheses that encompass the left child `(2 () ())` of the root, and then the parentheses that encompass the right child `(3 () ( 4 () ) ( )))` from the root. The left node has no children `()()` while the right node has a child `(4()())`, and this is also a leaf `()()`.

I tried to create the function but I couldn't leave it with the expected output... the result of my function comes out like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

my code, trying to create a function, was this:

```
def show(node):
    string = []                                       
    if not node: 
        return      
    print(node.dado)
    show(node.left) 
    show(node.right)
```

Comment: shouldn't be there, I already organize the code

Comment: What part of your code could ever print a parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already implemented **inorder** traverse of your tree, which is good. You missed two things:

1. What do you want to print if node is null? -> empty brackets
2. What do you want to print before and after each step? -> brackets

So your function could look like that:

```
def show(node):
    if not node:
        print("()", end="")
        return
    print(f"({node.dado} ", end="")
    show(node.left)
    print(" ", end="")
    show(node.right)
    print(")", end="")
```

The **end** parameter of `print` prevent it to adding newline character at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You should indeed use recursion for this, but your attempt is not adding any parentheses, and outputs line breaks.

For the base case -- when a node is `None` -- the string should be "()". When the node is not `None`, it is a matter of combining the recursive results of the two children with the node's own value.

Here is a function for that:

```
def serialize(node):
    if not node:
        return "()"
    return f"({node.dado} {serialize(node.left)} {serialize(node.right)})"
```

Here is how you could use it:

```
# Create tree that's used as example in the question
root = BinaryTree(1, BinaryTree(2), BinaryTree(3, None, BinaryTree(4)))
# Create the string for it
print(serialize(root))   # (1 (2 () ()) (3 () (4 () ())))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation:

```
def show(node):
    print(end='(')
    if node:
        print(node.dado, end=' ')
        show(node.left)
        print(end=' ')
        show(node.right)
    print(end=')')
```